# phalcon Dynamic Class creation fails with error?

Tags: php, phalcon

I am trying to create dynimic model class with a model function inside the user model, however for some reason it unable to identify the class location. it gives me an error

```
Fatal error: Class 'VarEducation' not found
```

below is the function

```
public function partner()
{
    $view_service=new ViewService();
    $partner_vars_check=$view_service->getUserVarPartnerModelCheckMappingArray();
    foreach($partner_vars_check as $partner_key=>$partner_var){
        $table= str_replace("p_","var_",$partner_key);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table."
                WHERE id='" . $this->{$partner_key} . "'
                ORDER BY id DESC";
        $partner_obj = new $partner_var();
        $this->{$partner_key} = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple(null, $partner_obj,
            $partner_obj->getReadConnection()->query($sql));
    }
}
```

Any idea on what causing this ?

data supplied by the view service is as below

```
public function getUserVarPartnerModelCheckMappingArray() { 

    return array( 
        'p_education' => 'VarEducation', 
        'p_body' => 'VarBody', 
        'p_ethnicity' => 'VarEthnicity', 
        'p_religion' => 'VarReligion', 
        'p_family' => 'VarFamily', 
    ); 
}
```

Comment: use proper namespaces probably? Code looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you do, if you have model hidden in any namespace, you have to deliver full namespaces with your mapping array. Lets say, all your models are in namespace of `Application\Models`, you have to use it this way:

```
public function getUserVarPartnerModelCheckMappingArray() { 

    return array( 
        'p_education' => '\Application\Models\VarEducation', 
        'p_body' => '\Application\Models\VarBody', 
        'p_ethnicity' => '\Application\Models\VarEthnicity', 
        'p_religion' => '\Application\Models\VarReligion', 
        'p_family' => '\Application\Models\VarFamily', 
    ); 
}
```

Not saying that I would rather switch/case over such a small amount of options and use models directly, instead of building SQL by hand.

Comment: although your solution works, i dnt knw how it works without the namespace if i just do new VarEducation (without the dynamic creation)

Comment: Dynamic creation seems to run out of namespace it is called so you should deliver full namespace to make it work. Qualifies for phpwtf

Answer (score 1):

Phalcon should load classes correctly even if the class name is a variable. Try isolating the problem down to just:

```
$myClass='VarEducation';
$partner_obj = new $myClass();
```

Also try commenting out that particular model from your model list and see if your other models work, perhaps there's an error in finding that particular model but not others. Check your `/app/config/loader.php` file and make sure you're registering your models directory. Then make sure the file `VarEducation.php` exists in your models directory as well as your other models. Also make sure that the class name inside the file matches the file name, and you've named the class `VarEducation`. Also make sure it's not namespaced. Also make sure you didn't forget the leading `<?php` and that the file doesn't have any errors. If all else fails, you can simply load the class from your loader.php file with something like:

```
$loader->registerClasses(array(
    'VarEducation' => $config->application->modelsDir.'/VarEducation.php'
));
```

Make sure a simple test for the model works: `$x=new VarEducation();` I suggest doing this from your index controller under a `test` action.  If none of this works, comment on this post with your results when trying my suggestions and I'll update my answer.